# How to decode an animated gif File in MFC2010

Tags: c++, image, mfc

Deal all,

I need to decode an animated gif format picture into some bitmap files in MFC2010. Is there any library to decode a gif picture? I cannot use GDIPlus because the program has to run on windows XP. I do appreciate if someone provides me with a library, Activex, dll or anything similar.

Many Thanks,
Shervin Zargham

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple using ImageMagick's C++ API ([Magick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/)) :

```
/* list of Image to store the GIF's frames */
std::vector<Magick::Image> imageList; 

/* read all the frames of the animated GIF */
Magick::readImages( &imageList, "animated.gif" );

/* optionnally coalesce the frame sequence depending on the expected result */
Magick::coalesceImages( &imageList, imageList.begin(), imageList.end());

/* store each frame in a separate BMP file */
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < imageList.size(); ++i) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "frame" << i << ".bmp";
    imageList[i].write(ss.str());
}
```

Comment: Dear Zankinster,
I have downloaded the Magick and followed the instruction to install it on my system. However I encountered a problem at the first step. I opened and converted the configure.sln under visual studio 2010. I received an error when I pressed the play button to run the program; stating that “unable to start the program configure.exe… the system cannot find the specific file.”  
I do appreciate if you provide me the instructions to install it under visual 2010.
Many Thanks,
Shervin Zargham

Comment: @shervin I suppose you're following the [*advance installation instructions*](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/advanced-windows-installation.php).  It look likes `configure` is either not compiled or not in the right directory, check you're compiling it in *release* not *debug*.

Comment: @Zankinster: I went to VisualMagick\configure folder and opened the configure.sln. I also sat the build configuration to Release. However I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: @Zankinster: How can I confirm the right directory for configure? I did right click on the configure in the solution explorer and pressed re-build all. Do you think I need to update my visual studio ?

Comment: @Zankinster: Thank you so much that you suggest me the Magick++library, although I was unsuccessful to use it. actually I spent alot of time but no result :(.

Comment: What's the variable `it`?

Comment: @Colliot a non declared iterator of `imageList`, I fixed the code to make it compilable.

Answer (score 1):

WIC (included in Vista, available for XP) offers `CLSID_WICGifDecoder`, a COM component.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. does it support animated gif? is it possible to provide me an example? is it very important for me to extract all the gif frame frames into set of bitmaps in order to do some processing on it.

Comment: @shervin: The interface explicitly supports frame count and frame number; GIF is the primary image format for which that's needed.

Comment: I have used WIC as you suggested to decode my GIF image. At this point I can access to all frames and draw them on screen but the problem is; the size of each image is different in each frame. so when I want to show all frame on screen in sequence, the animation moves because the width and height of each frame is different. I would be so grateful if you help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using ImageMagick's C++ API (Magick++) ,tested on VS210:

```
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;
using namespace Magick;

void kk(char * nombre, char *ext)
{
/* list of Image to store the GIF's frames */
std::list<Magick::Image> imageList; 
/* read all the frames of the animated GIF */
Magick::readImages(  &imageList, nombre );
/* compone las diferencias para obtener los cuadros reales */
Magick::coalesceImages(&imageList,imageList.begin( ),imageList.end( ));
/* store each frame in a separate BMP file */
 list <Magick::Image>::iterator it;
 int i=1;
 for ( it = imageList.begin( ); it != imageList.end( ); it++ , i++)
    {
    std::string name =  "frame" +  to_string((_Longlong)(i))  + ext ;
    it->write(name);
    }
}
int main( int /*argc*/, char ** argv)
{

  // Initialize ImageMagick install location for Windows
  InitializeMagick(*argv); 
  try {
    kk("luni0.gif", ".png"); // using  ".bmp", ".jpg", ".png", OK
    return 0;
  }
    catch( exception &error_ )
    {
      cout << "Caught exception: " << error_.what() << endl;
      return 1;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time, but I recall once using [OleLoadPicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693724%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to open GIF and PNG files on old versions of Windows, though the documentation seems to suggest that it's only for BMP, ICO, and WMF.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. does it support animated gif? is it possible to provide me an example? is it very important for me to extract all the gif frame frames into set of bitmaps in order to do some processing on it.

Comment: @shervin: Like I said, it was a long time ago, so I don't remember the details and I don't have access to the code.  It's possible things have changed, since the documentation makes no reference to GIF.  You would have to experiment.